# webdriver can not select from jQuery select menu dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to select from a dropdown menu which is over layered with the jQuery plugin call selectmenu. I am trying to select a visible text from that dropdown menu with webdriver.

the following is the page source

```
<body>
<form action="#">
<ul id="speedAa-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="speedAa-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 147px; height: 150px; left: 107.65px; top: -74.6px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-106">
<ul id="speedB-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="speedB-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 274px; left: 122.733px; top: 241.85px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-338">
<ul id="speedD-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown" aria-labelledby="speedD-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 400px; left: 122.733px; top: 557.75px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-970">
<ul id="files-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="files-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 147px; left: 93.65px; top: 571.2px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-310">
<ul id="filesC-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="filesC-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 147px; left: 93.65px; top: 779.1px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-343">
<ul id="filesB-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all customicons ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="filesB-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 147px; left: 93.65px; top: 750.65px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-376">
<div style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px;">
<div style="position: absolute; float: left; font-family: Trebuchet MS,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 8px 3px 3px; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-style: none solid solid; border-color: -moz-use-text-color rgb(204, 204, 204) rgb(204, 204, 204); -moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none; z-index: 999999; width: 144px; display: none;">
<ul id="speedA-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-selectmenu-menu-popup" aria-labelledby="speedA-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 147px; left: 107.65px; top: 105.95px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-35">
<ul id="speedC-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-selectmenu-open" aria-labelledby="speedC-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 173px; left: 107.65px; top: 450.3px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item-391">
<li class="whoo" role="presentation">
<li class="" role="presentation">
<li class="ui-selectmenu-item-selected ui-selectmenu-item-focus ui-state-hover" role="presentation">
**<a id="ui-selectmenu-item-391" aria-selected="true" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">Medium</a>**
</li>
<li class="" role="presentation">
<li class="ui-corner-bottom" role="presentation">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome dev tools and try to get xpath or, right click on element you want and inspect it, you will see where it is on the DOM.

Comment: Please don't use "txtspk" style abbreviations in your answers.

Comment: Indeed.  You can use the [edit] link below your answer to fix that.

Comment: Thanks tebel. I know i can get the xpaths, but the items on my dropdown menu changes very often and it's time consuming to change the xpaths of over 30 items and the list just get longer.

Comment: perhaps you can do use TestNG data provider feature that allows you to load up data from X data source.